# How do I secure a connection from a web role to SQL Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-worker-roles

We're trying to implement the Gatekeeper Design pattern as recommended in Microsoft Security Best Practices for Azure, but I;m having some trouble determining how to do that.

To give some background on the project, we're taking an already developed website using the traditional layered approach (presentation, business, data, etc.) and converting it over to use Azure. The client would like some added security built around this process since it will now be in the cloud.

The initial suggestion to handle this was to use Queues and have worker roles process requests entered into the queue. Some of the concerns we've come across are how to properly serialize the objects and include what methods we need run on that object as well as the latency inherent in such an approach.

We've also looked setting up some WCF services in the Worker Role, but I'm having a little trouble wrapping my head around how exactly to handle this. (In addition to this being my first Azure project, this would also be my first attempt at WCF.) We'd run into the same issue with object serialization here.

Another thought was to set up some web services in another web role, but that seems to open the same security issue since we won't be able to perform IP-based security on the request.

I've searched and searched but haven't really found any samples that do what we're trying to do (or I didn't recognize them as doing so). Can anyone provide some guidance with code samples? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer one of your questions specifically, you can secure access to a WCF service using X.509 certificates and implement message security; if you also need an SSL connection to protect data in transit you would need to use both message and transport security. It's not the simplest thing on earth, but it's possible. You can make it so only the servers that have the correct certificate can make the WCF request.  Take a look at this thread for more details and a few more pointers: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuresecurity/thread/1f77046b-82a1-48c4-bb0d-23993027932a

Also, WCF makes it easy to exchange objects as long as you mark them Serializable. So making WCF calls would dramatically simplify how you exchange objects back and forth with your client(s).

Answer (score 1):

Please do not take this the wrong way, but it sounds like you are in danger of over-engineering a solution based on the "requirement" that 'the client would like some added security'. The gatekeeper pattern that is described on page 13 of the [Security Best Practices For Developing Windows Azure Applications](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBcQFjAA&url=http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/3/E/73E4EE93-559F-4D0F-A6FC-7FEC5F1542D1/SecurityBestPracticesWindowsAzureApps.docx&rct=j&q=Microsoft%20Security%20Best%20Practices%20for%20Azure&ei=34qbTZ_zFpCaOsjwzZUH&usg=AFQjCNHKgGfzfQtS37g04WIn6O4H6C8z5g&sig2=ZKprH-7L-BeQripkyPOEPQ&cad=rja) document is a very big gun which you should only fire at large targets, i.e., scenarios where you actually need hardened applications storing highly sensitive data. Building something like this will potentially cost a lot of time & performance, so make sure you weigh pro's & con's thoroughly.

Have you considered leveraging [SQL Azure firewall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee621782.aspx) as an additional (and possibly acceptable) security measure? You can specify access on an IP address level and even configure it programmatically through stored procedures. You can block all external access to your database, making your Azure application (web/worker roles) the only "client" that is allowed to gain access.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, but I got pulled on to another project. The client in question has their security model based on a web server that accesses a WCF (or web) service through a firewall which then accesses the database through a second firewall so that there are two firewalls between the open internet and the datastore. The client in question will be storing SSNs (which we'll be encrypting in the database) so they are very concerned about security. Your suggestion is how I'm designing my current Azure project, but this next project has stronger security requirements.

Comment: OK. Please provide a clear question, if possible. What specifically are you looking for? A sample implementation of the gatekeeper pattern? Input on how to serialize objects for storage in queues, of to transfer over (WCF) services? If at all possible, edit your original question & clarify. Thanks!